# Is there a way to stop double quotes from being stripped from javascript object property names?

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to use a third party email service, and I need to send them email addresses for visitors to our site. I am using `{"$email": email}` as this is the format they want, but when I console.log() the object, it is appearing as `{$email: email}`. It strips out the quotes and I need them. Is there a way to force JS to include these quotes? Thank you!

Edit: replying to blex in the comments talking about JSON.stringify-ing the object, this is my full code:

```
let reqPayload = [
        "identify",
        {
          // prettier-ignore
          "$email": email,
        },
      ];
      console.log(JSON.stringify(reqPayload));
      return await _learnq.push(JSON.stringify(reqPayload));
```

The stringify didn't work for me (:

Comment: The console _represents_ the Object without quotes around the keys, but if you stringify it as JSON, they'll be there: `console.log( JSON.stringify(obj) );`

Comment: @blex See my edit (:

Comment: This code [logs the JSON with quotes around the keys](https://jsfiddle.net/fn5pcqga/)

Comment: If you're using a library to call the API, it probably (almost certainly) calls `stringify()` itself, you shouldn't do that when pushing into the array.

Comment: What is `_learnq`?

Comment: @Barmar It is a 3rd party script we have running on our site. In their docs they gave me a  format for the array I pass them.

Comment: @blex Interesting. When I console.log() it and check the chrome dev tools, it prints without the quotes

Comment: That's just the way the console shows objects. The quotes aren't part of the value, it's just the way you wrote strings.

Comment: @StevenBoyce The issue you're having does not seem possible to me when using `JSON.stringify`. By definition, this method returns valid JSON, where quotes are required. I'm guessing your code example does not show the reality of your actual code. If you can provide a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (just enough code which we can run ourselves without changing anything and that reproduces your issue), it will make it easier for anyone to try and help you

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys for your help in better understanding JSON (: Long story short, the third party I was working with told me that I "needed" the double quotes on that object property, but I figured out what was going wrong actually had nothing to do with the object and that it was formatted correctly. Thank you again!